# RFE giving same accuracy for different number of features selected

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm, rfe

In the program, I am scanning a number of brain samples taken in a time series of 40 x 64 x 64 images every 2.5 seconds. The number of 'voxels' (3D pixels) in each image is thus ~ 168,000 ish (40 * 64 * 64), each of which is a 'feature' for an image sample.

I thought of using Recursive Feature Elimination (RFE). Then follow this up with Principle Component Analysis (PCA) because of the rediculously high n to perform dimensionality reduction.

There are 9 classes to predict. Thus a multi class classification problem. Starting with RFE:

```
estimator = SVC(kernel='linear')
rfe = RFE(estimator,n_features_to_select= 20000, step=0.05)
rfe = rfe.fit(X_train,y_train)
X_best = rfe.transform(X_train)
```

Now perform PCA :

```
X_best = scale(X_best)

def get_optimal_number_of_components():
    cov = np.dot(X_best,X_best.transpose())/float(X_best.shape[0])
    U,s,v = svd(cov)
    print 'Shape of S = ',s.shape

    S_nn = sum(s)

    for num_components in range(0,s.shape[0]):
        temp_s = s[0:num_components]
        S_ii = sum(temp_s)
        if (1 - S_ii/float(S_nn)) <= 0.01:
            return num_components

    return s.shape[0]

n_comp = get_optimal_number_of_components()
print 'optimal number of components = ', n_comp

pca = PCA(n_components = n_comp)
pca = pca.fit(X_best)
X_pca_reduced = pca.transform(X_best)
```

Train the reduced component dataset with SVM

```
svm = SVC(kernel='linear',C=1,gamma=0.0001)
svm = svm.fit(X_pca_reduced,y_train)
```

Now transform the training set to RFE-PCA reduced and make the predictions

```
X_test = scale(X_test)
X_rfe = rfe.transform(X_test)
X_pca = pca.transform(X_rfe)

predictions = svm.predict(X_pca) 

print 'predictions = ',predictions
print 'actual = ',y_test
```

I trained it for a subset of my data and got **76.92%**. I'm not too worried about the low number because it is trained only against 1/12 of my dataset.

I tried doubling the training size and get **92%** accuracy. This is pretty good. But then I trained against the entire dataset and saw an accuracy of **92.5%**

So I got a 0.5% increase in accuracy for 6 times the dataset increase. Furthermore, the data samples aren't noisy. So nothing is wrong with the samples.

Also, for 1/12 th the dataset training size, I get the same 76.92% when I choose n_features_to_select = 1000. (The same for 20000!!) while performing RFE. There must be something wrong here. Why do I get the same performance when selecting such a less number of features?

Comment: How likely is this to be explained by the data? How big is the expected ROI in your imaging data? I would start by looking at whether the 1000 features are a subset of the 20000 features, if so then look at spatial map of the voxels and ask yourself whether your classification accuracy could be explained by the region that your features span.

Comment: Most of the features contribute to noise. But around 20 K are different. I used another technique instead of RFE to extract features and noticed an increase in accuracy until n_features = 20K. After this, accuracy decreases (indicating noise) . So choosing 20K was actually ideal. There is no reason 1k sould give the same results